# Android App crashes on OneSignal push notification

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I developed a React Native app that crashes every time a push notification from OneSignal is received while the app is active.

The error is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzc`.

If I receive the notification when the app is on background, there is no problem.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "17.0.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        appCompatVersion = "1.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
           if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
              details.useVersion '17.0.0'
           }
           if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
              details.useVersion '17.0.0'
             }
           }
         }
        google()
        mavenLocal()

        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        maven {
           url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation/android/libs"
        }

            maven {
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android/libs"
            }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

And my app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

Project background_geolocation = project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
apply from: "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/app.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 200
        versionName "24.10"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation-locker')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_slider')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-iap')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-webrtc')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-incall-manager')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0"
    addUnimodulesDependencies()
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// [Added by react-native-background-geolocation] Purge debug sounds from release build.
def purgeBackgroundGeolocationDebugResources(applicationVariants) {
    if ((rootProject.ext.has("removeBackgroundGeolocationDebugSoundsInRelease")) && (rootProject.ext.removeBackgroundGeolocationDebugSoundsInRelease == false)) return
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            println("[react-native-background-geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build")
            variant.mergeResources.doLast {
                delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeResources.outputDir, includes: ["raw_tslocationmanager*"]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know where the problem could come from?

Comment: What version of OneSignal do you use?

Comment: It seems there is a bug in OneSignal lib https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/286, they recommend ti use their plugin https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/286#issuecomment-337885909.

Comment: I suspect that this might be an issue with code obfuscation. If you closly observe the name of the method i.e. "zzc" it is an renamed method. You need to check you mapping.txt file and find this string and that way you will find the equalent method name. Just mark an entry in your proguard configuration file to skip  obfuscation for this method.

Answer (score 3):

This could either happen with if;

1. The OneSignal SDK version is in your app is older than 3.6.0
2. Your using an Android Support Library version older than 26
3. Or if another GCM / FCM BroadcastReceiver in your app is also
   displaying a notification

According your build script 2 is fine. And you you need to apply the OneSignal gradle plugin in your project.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin: [0.10.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines of code at the top in `app/build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

After adding the above code, goto command prompt, navigate to the android folder of the react-native project and run `gradlew clean`. Finally run the project.

Do let me know if same issue is faced.

Comment: hello having the same issue still in android 9 and 10. lower versions are working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This error is arising due to conflict with firebase and google services used in onesignal sdk. If you can use 16.1.0 as your version of googleplay services, com.google.android.gms and if it doesn't help try to downgrade firebase as well. You can check https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/build.gradle for reference. Kindly post back the response.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this to the top. I think you probably don't activate the plugin.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Comment: still not working in <8 versions of android devices.